# util.Calendar vs sql.Date in Android

Tags: android, date, calendar, android-sqlite

What is the preferred data structure to use for objects that will interact with an Android sqlite database?  util.Calendar or sql.Date?  I want to use the less deprecated Calendar because my objects will be used outside of the database but I don't want to have a ton of conversions every time I load my database to my objects and vice-versa for performance reasons.